# When is pre-decrement applied in a for loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop

I am trying to implement [an algorithm that is specified using some C style pseudocode](http://cr.yp.to/salsa20.html).

The bulk of the algorithm is a `for` loop:

```
for (i = 20;i > 0;i -= 2) 
{
    //...snip
}
```

It is claimed that the loop runs **ten** times:

> The entire series of modifications is a series of 10 identical double-rounds.

I've ported the algorithm to my own language, and my results do not match the test vectors. So i'm trying to pick apart the minutia of the C-language in order to figure out what i could be doing wrong.

Perhaps the reason my code does not match the result of the test vectors is that it is supposed to only run **nine** times:

```
| i  | i -= 2 | i > 0 | Perform iteration |
|----|--------|-------|-------------------|
| 20 | 18     | Yes   | Yes - 1           |
| 18 | 16     | Yes   | Yes - 2           |
| 16 | 14     | Yes   | Yes - 3           |
| 14 | 12     | Yes   | Yes - 4           |
| 12 | 10     | Yes   | Yes - 5           |
| 10 |  8     | Yes   | Yes - 6           |
|  8 |  6     | Yes   | Yes - 7           |
|  6 |  4     | Yes   | Yes - 8           |
|  4 |  2     | Yes   | Yes - 9           |
|  2 |  0     |  No   | No                |
```

If i were to read the `if` statement logically, it is only executed nine times.

There's still the confusion of why they say it runs **ten** rounds, but then use **20** as the initial value.

I tried duplicating the logic i see (execute it one less times than documented), but my results still don't match. Unfortunately i don't have access to any functional code to compare my results against a known good implementation. So i may be barking up the wrong tree.

Am i barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Doesn't this work the same way in C#?

Comment: How can someone with 60 thousand-plus reputation not know how a for loop works?

Comment: _"Unfortunately i don't have access to any functional code to compare my results against a known good implementation. "_ Srsly? It easy to prove about your assumptions using a silly online IDE.

Comment: @Casey I mainly use modern languages. I rarely count down. And i don't believe i've ever used predecrement in a `for`.

Comment: @IanBoyd There isn't such thing like _predecrement_ in counting `for()` loops. I'd suspect you're using c# `for()` loops to iterate on lists mainly.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ What i meant was that i don't have access to functional code. I do have the C style pseudo-code; which may or may not work exactly as the algorithm intents on the compiler/language/endian/platform that i happen to use.

Comment: @IanBoyd _"algorithm intents on the compiler/language/endian/platform "_ none of these applies to a counting c++ `for()` loop. The last part is always executed after the body was executed, as long the condition yields `true`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ What i meant was that i don't have access to functional implementation of the code i am trying to port. I had not considered simply downloading an C IDE and compiling a test program. I've spent six hours on this; and i couldn't see the forest for the trees. The only thing i could see is how many times the loop runs, which is complicated by the fact that the linked algorithm uses 20/10 loops, while the canonical version uses 8/4 loops (or is it [16/8 - the rfc isn't clear](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-josefsson-scrypt-kdf-00)). So in this haze of iteration counts i turned to SO.

Comment: @IanBoyd _"So in this haze of iteration counts i turned to SO."_ So hopefully we could help to lift _the haze_ a bit for you :-) ...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Turns out i'm exhausted, frustrated, and blinded to the fact that there isn't even a pre-decrement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third part of the `for` condition is executed *after* the iteration.

The loop runs 10 times with `i` being 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2 for the body of each iteration.

Comment: That would mean that the use of *pre* decrement is a red-herring; that pre and post decrement are equivalent in a `for` loop?

Comment: The term "pre decrement" normally refers to the expression `--x`  (which does not appear in your code) but `--x` and `x--` are equivalent if they are the only thing in a statement, because the value of the expression is ignored. (The expression only exists for its side-effect of modifying x).

Comment: Oh my god; you're right. Man i am exhausted. That explains that. Although i'm back to square one trying to figure out why my port doesn't match the test vectors.

Answer (score 2):

A for loop goes "initialization, test, body, increment, test, body, increment, test, body, etc." The increment isn't applied before the first test.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, if you want to go from the last to the first element in a for loop but don't want the ugly:

```
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

You can use:

```
for (let i = arr.length; i-- > 0;)
```

Example:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for (let i = arr.length; i-- > 0;) {
  console.log(`arr[${i}] is: ${arr[i]}`);
}
```

Had you used pre-decrement here, the last iteration (which is the first element of the array) would have been missing:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for (let i = arr.length; --i > 0;) {
  console.log(`arr[${i}] is: ${arr[i]}`);
}
```